# Query a specific time range data from cosmos db and store it in sql database via azure data factory

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory V2 and want to copy the json data stored as documents from Azure cosmos db to a azure sql table, using a SQL query.

**Situation:**
I want to query just the last hour json files from Cosmos db and store it in sql table.
To do that, I create a new Trigger in my Data factory which recurrence the sql query each 1 hour.

**Problem:**
At first I wrote a query that read all data from cosmos db and it work fine, but I want to query just the data which stored within the last hour in cosmos db.

**What i need?** 
In Sql, how to write a query to get just the new files which stored within the last hour in the cosmos db ?

Comment: Try `SELECT  *
FROM    Whatever
WHERE   myTime > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())`

Comment: Its not working, I have this error.
BadRequest
Message: Identifier 'HOUR' could not be resolved

Comment: Try modify `HOUR` to `HH`.

Comment: Message1: Identifier 'HH' could not be resolved.
Message2: DATEADD' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @MahmoudSwaid What's the format of your time? You log it by youself or you just use "_ts" which is generated by cosmos db ? What's the sql you are using now?

Comment: the format that i had in the json file is like "5/9/2018 8:41:11 AM" and also i had another format like "2018-05-09T8:41:11.619Z"

Comment: @MahmoudSwaid Any updates now? Does my answer helps you?

Comment: sorry for late. i could not query the data using your function. Because of that i coud not mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define an udf in your cosmos db collection.

```
function getLastHourTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var a = date.setHours(-1);
    return a;
}
```

Modify your sql to :

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.time >= udf.getLastHourTime()
```

Note: udf.getLastHourTime() returns `Unix time stamp` , you need to match the format.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This consumes lot of RUs. Any alternative for this?