# Cosmos db sql api query with datetime filter in WHERE condition

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Trying to get those documents whose modified date(datetime) is equal to (currentdate -7) but NOT working, pseudocode as below

**"SELECT * FROM c where c.LastModifiedDate = (GetCurrentDate-7)"**

How to do it using cosmosdb sql api? without udf because we have timer trigger based Azure function  which querying Cosmos DB using **above** SQL query directly when it get triggered each time and binding results to a parameter of the function.

```
    [FunctionName("TimerCosmosDbWriteExample")]
    public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,
        TraceWriter log,
        [CosmosDB(
            databaseName: "Database",
            collectionName: "Collection",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "MyConnectionString",
            SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM c where c.LastModifiedDate = GetCurrentDate-7")] IEnumerable<Entity> documents)
    {
     //function body -- loop through retrieved documents & process it 
    }
```

Comment: Is there that much of a difference between using the `[DocumentDb]` parameter attribute vs just initializing the Cosmos Client in the function and executing that same code? That way you can at least manipulate the date and parameters. I sadly don't know an easier way to do it.

Comment: Take a look at this article here that talks about working with dates in Cosmos DB. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 viewpoints for your reference:

1.Since you invoke the sql query in azure function, you could calculate the `currentDate-7` with code,then pass it into query sql as an parameter.It's a common usage and just match the format of `LastModifiedDate` column.

2.I don't know why you said you can't use udf with sql query in azure function,it doesn't make sense. As i know,UDF is part of SQL.Please refer to my previous case:[Query a specific time range data from cosmos db and store it in sql database via azure data factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50406694/query-a-specific-time-range-data-from-cosmos-db-and-store-it-in-sql-database-via/50408328#50408328)

Comment: Both of the above approaches wont work with azure function declarative bindings.

Comment: @prkat Why are you set on using the bindings?

Comment: Since CosmosDB binding is out-of-box it is straight forward implementation & less maintenance.